# Ajax repetindo dados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Meu código ajax está repetindo todo o select quando é cadastrado uma nova tarefa por conta do for que navega em toda a array novamente.

Insert de informações:

```
$('#task').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var u_dep = $('#dep').val();
    var u_nfe = $('#nfe').val();
    var u_pass = $('#pass').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/FAST-ANSWER/inserir.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { dep: u_dep, nfe: u_nfe, pass: u_pass },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (result) {
        $('#dep').val('');
        $('#nfe').val('');
        $('#pass').val('');
        getTasks(); //função para trazer a tarefa assim que cadastrada
        //Todavia está fazendo repetir os dados mostrados anteriormente
    });
});
```

Select de informações:

```
function getTasks() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/FAST-ANSWER/select.php',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (result) {
        console.log(result);

        
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            $('.list').prepend('<ul><li class="onDemand">' + result[i].NFE + ' - ' + result[i].CLERK + ' - ' + result[i].SECTOR + '</li></ul>');
        }
    });
}
```

Como eu poderia alterar a estrutura do meu for para que ele me trouxesse apenas o item que acabou de ser cadastrado?

Exemplo de como está:

- segundo item cadastrado (Prossegue normalmente)
- primeiro item cadastrado (Aqui o código mostra novamente o que já fora cadastrado)
- primeiro item cadastrado

Comment: **Caso haja alguma inconformidade com a pergunta**, favor informar ou, se possível, sugerir uma alteração, desde já agradeço a todos pelo suporte!

Comment: não apaga os itens existentes antes de adicionar novamente?

Comment: Não, ela apenas escreve novamente, acumulando as informações antes já mostradas

Comment: acho que não perguntei bem :) eu quis dizer "não deveria antes de fazer `prepend` excluir o que já existe na lista?"

Comment: Sim, seria possível! mas existe alguma outra maneira? tenho receio de não ser uma boa prática e acabar me habituando a ela

Comment: tem, comparar cada elemento de result com o que já existe para não adicionar novamente, o que dá muito mais trabalho

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Ricardo! Consegui realizar por ambas formas, mas decidi manter da segunda.